# Error using Option.value_exn

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-core, option-type

I was trying to unwrap the result of `List.max_elt` of a non-empty list, which should always exist, so I thought `Option.value_exn` would be the correct tool. But it fails with a strange error:

```
# List.range 0 10 |> List.max_elt ~cmp:compare;;
- : int option = Some 9

# Option.value_exn (Some 9);;
- : int = 9

# List.range 0 10 |> List.max_elt ~cmp:compare |> Option.value_exn;;
Error: This expression has type
         ?here:Lexing.position ->
         ?error:Base.Error.t -> ?message:string -> 'a Base.option -> 'a
       but an expression was expected of type int option -> 'b
```

Can anybody explain this error to me?

I'm using OCaml 4.05.0 and the latest Core library.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that something (I'm guessing `Option.value_exn`) takes optional arguments. When you write it as `Option.value_exn x` OCaml knows that the optional arguments aren't being used, but when you write it as `x |> Option.value_exn` it doesn't.